# Not Able Receive Data from AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django

I am trying to send Parameters to Django View, but showing blanks. The following is my Angularjs Code:

```
      $scope.APbaseHttp=function(x){
         $scope.unkm='/budareaemp/';
         alert("in APBASE");
         var dt = $.param({
          ap:x
         });
           var cn = {
           headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
          }
      };      
      alert("dt Value :"+x);
      $http.post($scope.unmk,dt,cn).then(function(response){
          $scope.appdata=response.data;
          $scope.nm="Success";
      });
   }
```

The Value x, when I put alert, is showing the expected value from HTML.

This is my Django code:

```
@csrf_exempt
def getEmpAppwise(request):
    print("In GET EMP AppWise.....................................................................")
    x=QueryDict(request.body)
    y=len(request.body)
    h=HttpRequest.body
    print('-rrrrrrrr :',x,y,h)
    #print('oooooooooo',json.loads(x))
    print("Get EMp Wisee ",request.POST)
    print("Get EMp Wiseeeeee ",request.POST.get('ap'))
    ap=request.POST.get('ap') 

    print("::::::::::I am in Get APP Name :::::::::::::::",ap)
```

I tried in all possible ways with the help of StackOverflow, but could not get success.

The display shows as follows

```
<QueryDict:{}> 0
None
```

When I looked at parameters passed, in Firefox, it is showing as "No Parameters Passed".

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you are doing with that code.

To access the parameters in a form-encoded POST request, you use `request.POST`, which is a querydict. So:

```
print(request.POST)
```

**Edit**

You're doing all kinds of odd things here. AngularJS's `$http` service will automatically transform an object in the data parameter into JSON, see [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses). You've included an extra header to say that this is form-encoded data; but it won't be. You should remove that `cn` object altogether.

On the Django side, since it is receiving JSON not form-encoded data you need to take the request body and deserialize it:

```
data = json.loads(request.body)
ap = data.get('ap')
```

Comment: I am trying to post value from AngularJs to Django View. I am trying to get the value posted by AngularJS into Django View. When I am displaying, I am not getting the value. I have used request.POST also, but it is showing Empty

Comment: It is not a form based, it is populated thru a drop down. The selected value I want to pass thru angularjs into Django View

Comment: Sir, Thank you for looking into. I made changes as you mentioned.

Comment: But Still not working. I am getting the following error. @csrf_exempt
def getEmpAppwise(request):
    print("In GET EMP AppWise View")
    y=json.loads(request.body)
    a=y.get('ap')
    print("::::::::::I am in Get APP Name :::::::::::::::",a)

Comment: JSONDecodeError at /budareaemp/

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/budareaemp/
Django Version:  2.1.3
Exception Type:  JSONDecodeError
Exception Value:  

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Exception Location:  C:\Python36\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode, line 357
Python Executable:  C:\Python36\python.exe
Python Version:  3.6.4

Comment: Can you print the raw value of `request.body`? But also note that the URL path "/budareaemp" does not match what you claim to be sending in the JS, ie "/budareaemp/" with a slash, and also it is a GET not a POST. Are you sure the JS is actually being called and is sending the request? What is actually triggering the APbaseHttp function?

Comment: I have put the Alert in my JS, it is able to show the value. The control is coming upto the View. In the view I am not able to fetch the value passed. the data When I tried to print raw data, I am getting JSONDecodeError.Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/budareaemp/
Request method:GET
Remote address:127.0.0.1:8000
Status code:500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Yes it's coming to the view, but *not* as a POST, and not to the URL you specified. So either something is redirecting from /budareaemp/ to /budareamp, or the browser is submitting a GET straight after the JS does the POST.

Comment: What is triggering APbaseHttp is as follows   </br> <a id="a1" class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="k in appdata" ng-click="APbaseHttp(k.BudgetArea)"